# Spotfire - Marking with a Y-Axis Custom expression

Tags: spotfire

Currently, I'm trying to create a combination chart (graph) in Spotfire where a specific record could be bucketed into one or more categories. For example, I have a category for newly created invoices as well as a category for invoices that are in process. Easily, you can have an invoice that is both newly created and in process, and I want to show these both these categories as separate series so that I can monitor each category independently (i.e. if I have a population of 600 invoices of which 500 are newly created and 300 are in process, I want to be able to drill down into the 500 newly created invoices or the 300 in process ones, regardless of overlap)

Currently, I can create the graph by using a CASE statement for the Y-Axis (i.e. if it's a "New Invoice" Then 1, ELSE 0) so I can get the graph to show the correct number of records. However, with this method, Spotfire doesn't know that only records that satisfy the case statement should be marked; therefore, if I try to mark these specific transactions, I get detail for all transactions.

Has anyone figured out a way to get around this? Obviously, if each criteria was independent, the marking could be done really easily, but since it isn't, I can't seem to crack what seems like a very simple problem.

Comment: Instead of using details on demand you can "Create a Details Visualization" Table and then, your selection will only show the desired results. Details on Demand will always show all data which was responsible for the aggregation, as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a calculated column that splits your data set accordingly.  For example, use an if statement or case statements to have your calculated column return "New Invoice", "In-progress Invoice", or "New and In-progress Invoice" based on your specific evaluation criteria for determining which bin each invoice falls in to.  Then you could series the graph by that new column and it should work when you mark the specific invoices.

Answer (score 0):

See if creating a hierarchy like [OLD or NEW], and place [STATUS] (which may be Open, or In Progress, or Closed) below the [OLD or NEW] column. Place this hierarchy in X axis.

You would see like OLD which can be further translated to either Open, In Progress, or Closed, and the same with New.